# Crystal report Multiple Queries 

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

I Want to show result from multiple tables from database but how to set property (Setdatasource) for the same in vb.net. Iam using visual studio 2008 back end sql compact 2005

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use sub-reports to show results from different queries. If you can join all results in one query, you can think about use a stored procedure to pre-process your results before you present it on the report.

Comment: Do you have access/permissions to create stored procedures / functions / views, etc.?  You might be able to do it in a UNIONed view or Joins.  In Crystal?  I don't think that Crystal will handle multiple datasources in one report.